# CDI been creating new record instead of updating

Tags: jsf, cdi

I have changed my JSF manged bean to a CDI named bean. However I get a strange behavior that when I update a record using JPA `merge()` through EJB, a new record is being created instead of updating the entity.

**my previous implementation**

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class bean implements serializable{
    @EJB Service service;
    private Entity entity;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init(){
         int id = 1;
         this.entity = (Entity) service.findEntity(Entity.class, 1);

    }

    //invoke after editing entity
    public void update(){
         service.update(entity);
    }
}

@Stateless
public class Service implements Serializable{
    @PersistenceContext(unitName="unitName")
    private EntityManager em;    

    public void update(Object obj){
        em.merge(obj);
    }

    public Object find(Class klass, object pk){
        return em.find(klass, pk);
    }

}
```

Result: entity is being updated

**My new implementation**

```
@Named
@ConversationScoped
public class bean implements Serializable{
    //unchanged
}
```

**Result:** entity is not being updated, and instead a new record is being created with all fields being duplicated except the id (pk) as it is an auto generated integer, and a new id is generated for the new record; Why is this happening?

Comment: Are you passing the same object to update() as you get when calling getReference() (or the way you load objects through the entity manager) ?

Comment: @AdrianMitev Yes its the same object with the same id (pk).. However, when passing the new object to jpa another row is created with all fields being duplicated except the id (as it is an auto generated integer).

Comment: At what point are you creating the conversation?

Comment: @BalusC in this question there is Java language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you really want to chane the scope of your bean to ConversationScoped. I would have thought that you would use

```
"javax.faces.view.ViewScoped"
```

[not <strike>javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped!!</strike>] and just use @Named. Changing a bean scope changed the whole semantics.

Comment: Note that this annotation was introduced in JSF 2.2 which is relatively new and that the OP didn't mention anywhere which JSF version exactly he is using.